# AutoHotKey: Getting the last key that was pressed

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to get the last key that was pressed by the user. I'm not talking about a hotkey; just a normal keypress.

If possible, I'd also like to have keys that AHK typed using `SendInput` be included. So if AHK just did `SendInput` for some keys, and I'm asking for the last key that was pressed, then I'd be given the last key that AHK emitted or the last key that the user typed, depending on who typed last.

I tried `A_PriorKey`, but it's problematic because when I tried it, it showed one of the keys that triggered the script, rather than the keys that came before the hotkeys, which is what I want.

Is what I want possible?

Comment: What about using `A_PriorHotKey` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a loop with Input, LastKey, L1 V ?

Comment: And have that running at all times? Sounds kinda wasteful, isn't it?

Comment: The loop will be waiting (and not looping) most of the time, only when you press a key will the (single line) loop be triggered. This should not be a problem for AutoHotKey or the resources on your system.

Comment: Anything before the FIRST Return in the script will be executed on startup. Wow, where did your comment go....